# Matlab GUI : Get a figure from an external application and show it in the GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

First of all thanks by advance and sorry for my bad English it is not my native tongue.

My level in MATLAB Gui is zero, but i need to make a simple application.

So i made the GUI with the built-in assistant.
I have a slider which go from 0 to 1 and a button 'Update'.
The goal is when you click on the button it get the value from the slider, send it to a function already made, get the figure returned by the function and show it in the GUI.

My function already have fh=figure in it and return it (as an output).

Here is a simplified version of the function :

```
    function fh = draw_something_2d(P,t)
    fh=figure
    hold on;
    %some treatment and a lot of plotting
    xlabel('Axe x')
    ylabel('Axe Y')
    zlabel('Axe Z')
    title('Title Of Things')
    hold off;
```

And my items have this tags : the button is named :button_maj and the slider : slider

Anyway i'm working on MATLAB R2014a.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

**EDIT**
By built-in assistant i mean the "GUIDE" assistant.

When i click the push button i want the figure which is made by an exterior function to show in my GUI.
In pseudo code it would be something like

```
    On_Click_PushButton{
     axe1.graphic=draw_something_2d(15,slider.getvalue());
    }
```

Comment: Can you use `image`, `imagesc` or `imshow` to show the image?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the problem and what you are you stuck on? I don't understand if your problem is with the plotting, or plotting inside the GUI or something else. Also by what do you mean by "external application"? From where you what to acquire the plots?

Comment: I edited to be more precise. Thanks you for taking care.

Answer (score 0):

Well i was not able to find a clean solution so i copy-pasted my code and accessed directly from the "on click" function. From within i was able to access directly a figure named "axe1" as standard matlab example show. It is not a clean solution but it is one.